# Multiprocessing with pandas read csv and threadpool executor

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas

I have a huge csv to parse by chyunk and write to multiple files

I am using pandas read_csv function to get chunks by chunks. It was working fine but slower than the performance we need. So i decided to do this parsing in threads

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)
            with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
                futures = executor.map(process, [df for df in pd.read_csv(
                    downloaded_file, chunksize=chunksize, compression='gzip', low_memory=False, skipinitialspace=True, encoding='utf-8')], file_index)
                for future in concurrent.futures.as_costmpleted(futures):
                    pass
```

Here is my function that has a responsibility to parse and write to csv

```
def process(df, file_index):
    """
    Process the csv chunk in a separate thread
        :param df:
        :param file_index:
        :param chunk_index:
    """
    chunk_index = random.randint(1, 200)
    print "start processing chunk"
    # some heaving processing...
    handle = open(outfile_name)
    df.to_csv(outfile_name, index=False,
                          compression='gzip', sep='\t', quoting=1, encoding='utf-8')
    handle.close()
    del df
    print "end processing chunk"
    return True
```

I never see my print debug lines and the cpu and memory reach to 100% and my script get killed.

It looks like the `read_csv` it self is always yielding and the `executor.map` is still waiting for the first argument.

Thanks

Comment: The whole point of chunksize is so that the entire data set is not loaded into memory at once. However, your code does exactly that, it takes a lazily evaluated (generator) object, and exhausts it into a list, which is as good as reading the original data set entirely.

Comment: Yes, but previously i tried using a `for` loop and i found out that the pool is not limited.  can you provide a code solution if possible ? Thank you

Comment: The `executor.map` is supposed to take one item at a time from list and i thought it would only go for another chunk once its finised the first one

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered keeping the second argument to the `executor.map` function lazy (generator)?

```
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(2)
df_generator = pd.read_csv(downloaded_file, 
                           chunksize=chunksize,
                           compression='gzip', 
                           low_memory=False, 
                           skipinitialspace=True, 
                           encoding='utf-8')

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    futures = executor.map(process, df_generator, file_index)
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        pass
```

[`df.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking) with a given chunksize will return a generator object and ensure iteration is lazy. This should ideally not cause memory overflow, if your chunksize is chosen well.

Comment: what is `as_completed` doing here ?

Comment: The inner for loop will iterate over the futures as and when the executor threadpool finishes processing them, i.e. once the "process" function returns for a particular chunk, that particular chunk will be available inside the future. They are not guaranteed to be in the same order as the data.

Comment: Doesn't this run into the same problem @Raheel originally mentioned? `executor.map` will collect all of `df_generator` (it's not evaluated lazily), which will consume all the memory.